# Interpolating a list item as a property?

Tags: java, freemarker

**Objective:** To use Freemarker to generate Java code of the following form

```
public void save(){
    helper.save();
}

public void load(){
    helper.load();
}

//Other such lifecycle methods
```

Basically, I have a handful of "lifecycle" method names and I want to generate code for each of them. However, I only generate a method if the model object passed in requires it. My model class looks like:

```
public class Model{
    private boolean load;
    private boolean save;
    //bools for other lifecycle methods

    public Model(boolean load, boolean save){
        this.load = load;
        this.save = save;
    }

    public boolean getLoad(){
        return load;
    }

    public boolean getSave(){
        return save;
    }
}
```

My freemarker template:

```
<#assign methodNames = ["load", "save"]>
<#list methodNames as method>
<#if model.method>
public void ${method}(){
    helper.${method}();
}
</#if>
</#list>
```

However, that `<#if>` statement does not work. Freemarker complains that `model.method` is `null`. It looks like Freemarker is looking for `getMethod()` in my model instead of resolving `model` to either `save` or `load` and then looking for `getSave()` or `getLoad()`.

I tried the following but in all cases Freemarker complains about one syntax error or another:

```
<#assign methodNames = ["load", "save"]>
<#list methodNames as method>
<#assign methodRequired = r"model.${method}">
<#if <@methodRequired?interpret>>
public void ${method}(){
    helper.${method}();
}
</#if>
</#list>
```

This fails with an error saying I cannot have that `<@methodRequired>` inside an `<#if>`. I also directly tried `<#if model.${method}>` but that obviously does not work.

For completeness, here's how I invoke the template:

```
//Obtain a writer object first. Then ...
Model model = new Model(true, false);
myTemplate.process(model, writer);
writer.close();
```

So, the question is - **How do I ask Freemarker to give me the value of a list variable from inside another model object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much like in other typical languages: `model[method]`. `model.method` is actually shorthand for `model["method"]`. And you can also write things like `model["foo" + someVar]`, so it's `someContainer[someKeyExpression]`.

Comment: That did the trick. All I had to do was use this syntax in the `if` condition: `<#if model[method]>`